# Write to serial device from uboot prompt

Tags: serial-port, u-boot

Is it possible to send a message to a serial device from the u-boot prompt? Like I would do in a linux terminal with `echo "Hello" > /dev/tty2`

Thanks

Comment: Is it resolved ? How ?

Comment: No, it was not solved. SEEMS like it is not possible without modifying uboot itself, but I had no significant answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to send data/write data in Serial port via Uboot. Loading Linux images over UART is possible in that case its possible to do write data to the serial device.

```
set line /dev/ttyUSB0
set speed 115200
send "hello"
```

You can just try to use echo or send from the U-boot terminal.

Right now I don't have access to U-boot from my device. This is what I did several times to just handshake serial device from U-boot.

Comment: I think those are kermit commands, run on the host computer.  The relevant u-boot command would be `loadb`.  But that's for transferring files to u-boot over the serial port, which doesn't sound like what you want.